# AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, correlation

I've been working with MSAL for almost three years, now I am facing a problem I am not able to fix, even if I've read a lot of posts:

```
"AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 
'c09036af-fd62-4db6-b27a-xxxxxxxxxxxx' named 'mySite.com'. Send an interactive authorization
request for this user and resource. Trace ID: 126a546f-a8b3-4176-8c74-e6a4c4851300 Correlation ID: 6cc0a067-ec3b-4b25-9caa-215620991f24 Timestamp: 2023-06-28 08:14:16Z"
```

I know, another question about granting apps in azure, but the point is that there are no grants required. Under `Configured permissions` there are no pending consents to grant. My application is a single application with no API application. It might be a scope issue, up today I always used the clientId as scope, in this case it does not work.

Any idea?

Edit:

After some tests I figured out the problem IS the scope. As suggested by @Rukmini as scope I set "{clientId}./default". Now the login works, but from my api (on the same domain) I get the following error:

```
401 oidc: id token issued by a different provider, expected "https://login.microsoftonline.com/9c0a3ae0-3f12-4197-a76d-xxxxxxxxxxxx/v2.0" got "https://sts.windows.net/9c0a3ae0-3f12-4197-a76d-xxxxxxxxxxxx/" []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created **Azure AD Application and Exposed an API** like below:

[image]

I tried to generate **access token** using below parameters via Postman:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:ClientID 
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

And I got the **same error** as below:

[image]

I got the error as I passed **scope** as `ClientID` and used `v2.0` endpoint.

The error "***AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID
'xxxx named 'abc'. Send an interactive authorization
request for this user and resource***" usually occurs if the admin has not consented for the permissions the user is trying to access.

To resolve the error, make sure to **grant Admin consent to the API permissions** like below:

[image]

**Note** that: Azure AD Supports passing ClientID as scope, but it depends on the endpoint you are making use of to authorize the request.

- With **`v2.0`** endpoint, you have to pass scope as `ClientID/.default` or `ClientID/scopename` like below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

scope:ClientID/.default OR ClientID/test.read
```

[image]

- With **`v1.0`** endpoint, you can pass **resource** as `ClientID` like below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/token

resource:ClientID
```

[image]

***If still the issue persists,*** check whether you are passing valid ClientID and granted required permissions to the Azure AD Application.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I am using MSAL library. However, following your example, what is `code` in the body?

Comment: What is the endpoint you are using to generate token

Comment: I understand, but in the body of your request you have a parameter called `code`. Where does it come from? BTW, I am using MSAL, cannot follow your example.

Comment: I solved it using as scope the clientId + `/.default` as you mentioned. Thanks